# Лендинг. Нужно, чтобы кнопка меню активировалась в зависимости от selection, который открыт

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

```
<section  id="menu">
<header class="header bg-blackblue fixed-top"  >
<div class="container " >
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  ">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.webp" alt=""></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav-justify mt-4 mt-md-0 mt-lg-0 mt-xl-0" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 offset-lg-2" >
<li class="nav-item ">
<a class="nav-link mr-lg-5 opensans activemenu"   aria-current="page" href="#menu" >Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link mr-lg-5 opensans"   href="#about"><span class="vl mr-lg-5 " ></span>About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link mr-lg-5 opensans"   href="#portfolio"><span class="vl mr-lg-5" ></span>Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link ml-lg-5 opensans" href="#contact">
<span class="vl mr-lg-5" ></span>Contact
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
</section>
```

Вот этот класс нужно задавать элементам меню:

```
<style>.activemenu{border-bottom: 1px solid #E2A300;}</style>


<section id="about"> ... </section> <section id="portfolio"> ...
</section> <section id="contact"> ... </section>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: Закрывающий тэг див после хедер должен стоять до..